# Non www to www redirection A record problem

Tags: dns, no-www

I have told my domain registrar to set my domain like this:
www.domain.com -> IP1
domain.com -> A record IP2

www.domain.com works properly, but non www returns %20 before the real url www.domain.com
so it look like %20www.domain.com in the address bar.

What can I do to make this work? I do not have access to the DNS settings (have to tell registrar what I want) or the root folder where is my website so the solution must be with the DNS via registrar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%20` is an ASCII character for [blank space](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm), so they have accidentally put in a white space before www. when configuring the DNS records. This is probably a result of cutting and pasting from an email!

You just need to mail them and ask them to remove the space.

Comment: thank you, I thought it was a simple thing, but nevertheless wanted to check with you people :)